# StackOverFlow Error with ProgressDialog.show() inside AsyncTask While Running Robolectric tests

Tags: android, junit, junit4, robolectric

Note: Already visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372042/progressdialog-show-inside-asynctask-stop-my-program-from-execution) link but not helpful.

**While running Robolectric Junit tests**, I am getting StackOverFlow Error caused by

> ProgressDialog.show()

Call made inside AsyncTask.

I have following kind of activity:

```
public abstract class TransactionFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.transction_layout);             
        SetUpService setup = new SetUpService();
        setup.execute();
    }

    private class SetUpService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(TransactionFragmentActivity.this);

        /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */
        /** application context. */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            SetUpService.this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
            SetUpService.this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
            SetUpService.this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
            // Setting data 
            Log.d(TAG,"doInBackground...");

            fetchData(); //some method doing work
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

following is the stacktrace:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
>       at org.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.newInstance(RobolectricInternals.java:39)
>       at org.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.directlyOn(RobolectricInternals.java:54)
>       at org.robolectric.Robolectric.directlyOn(Robolectric.java:366)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowView.directly(ShadowView.java:439)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowView.invalidate(ShadowView.java:168)
>       at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java)
>       at android.widget.TextView.setPadding(TextView.java:2122)
>       at android.view.View.recomputePadding(View.java:10914)
>       at android.view.View.resolvePadding(View.java:11584)
>       at android.view.View.resolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11524)
>       at android.view.View.onAttachedToWindow(View.java:11440)
>       at android.widget.TextView.onAttachedToWindow(TextView.java:4448)
>       at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:11755)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2424)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2424)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2424)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2424)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2424)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2424)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2424)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2424)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1201)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler.handleMessage(Choreographer.java:657)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.routeMessage(ShadowHandler.java:125)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.access$100(ShadowHandler.java:25)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler$1.run(ShadowHandler.java:110)
>       at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postDelayed(Scheduler.java:37)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.post(ShadowLooper.java:198)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.postDelayed(ShadowHandler.java:56)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.sendMessageDelayed(ShadowHandler.java:105)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.sendMessageAtTime(ShadowHandler.java:160)
>       at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.scheduleFrameLocked(Choreographer.java:479)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.postCallbackDelayedInternal(Choreographer.java:309)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.postCallbackDelayed(Choreographer.java:292)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.postCallback(Choreographer.java:266)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.scheduleTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:974)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setLayoutParams(ViewRootImpl.java:792)
>       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerImpl.java:343)
>       at android.app.Activity.onWindowAttributesChanged(Activity.java:2267)
>       at android.view.Window.setDefaultWindowFormat(Window.java:1226)
>       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.access$1300(PhoneWindow.java:105)
>       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.drawableChanged(PhoneWindow.java:2407)
>       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.fitSystemWindows(PhoneWindow.java:2345)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1203)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler.handleMessage(Choreographer.java:657)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.routeMessage(ShadowHandler.java:125)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.access$100(ShadowHandler.java:25)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler$1.run(ShadowHandler.java:110)
>       at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postDelayed(Scheduler.java:37)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.post(ShadowLooper.java:198)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.postDelayed(ShadowHandler.java:56)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.sendMessageDelayed(ShadowHandler.java:105)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.sendMessageAtTime(ShadowHandler.java:160)
>       at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.scheduleFrameLocked(Choreographer.java:479)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.postCallbackDelayedInternal(Choreographer.java:309)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.postCallbackDelayed(Choreographer.java:292)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.postCallback(Choreographer.java:266)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.scheduleTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:974)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setLayoutParams(ViewRootImpl.java:792)
>       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerImpl.java:343)
>       at android.app.Activity.onWindowAttributesChanged(Activity.java:2267)
>       at android.view.Window.setDefaultWindowFormat(Window.java:1226)
>       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.access$1300(PhoneWindow.java:105)
>       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.drawableChanged(PhoneWindow.java:2407)
>       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.fitSystemWindows(PhoneWindow.java:2345)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1203)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler.handleMessage(Choreographer.java:657)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.routeMessage(ShadowHandler.java:125)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.access$100(ShadowHandler.java:25)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler$1.run(ShadowHandler.java:110)
>       at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postDelayed(Scheduler.java:37)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.post(ShadowLooper.java:198)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.postDelayed(ShadowHandler.java:56)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.sendMessageDelayed(ShadowHandler.java:105)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.sendMessageAtTime(ShadowHandler.java:160)
>       at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.scheduleFrameLocked(Choreographer.java:479)
>       at............

Comment: try to initialize the `ProgressDialog` in onPreExecute.

Comment: and where is your `super.onPreExecute();` and `super.onPostExecute(success);` super clause.

Comment: @sourabhbans,  initializing the ProgressDialog in onPreExecute did not work, super.onPreExecute(); and super.onPostExecute(success);  is also not helping, still getting StackOverFlow error.

Answer (score 0):

try `final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext);`

Comment: Still getting StackOverFlow Error.

Comment: Did u find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

protected void onPreExecute() { 
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}
```

or

```
Activity act = (TransactionFragmentActivity) this;

private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(act);

protected void onPreExecute() { 
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Think it will work. Check it out and let me know.

Comment: Inside SetUpService (AsyncTask) getActivity() is not allowed as per compiler, and also casting of TransactionFragmentActivity to Activity didn't work.

Comment: okay, I am pretty sure that passing the Context to Progress dialog is the problem. and I don't have answer for that. please look into that area. your Async task was fine.

Comment: ok, but the code is working in Android Dev Env, I am getting error in Robolectric Test case execution, on the call of dialog.show() method, so not sure how to resolve this.